# Why is n a power of two for n over k even

Tags: binomial-coefficients

If $\binom{n}{k}$ is even for every $1 \le k \lt n$, $n$ has to be a power of two. I'm searching for an elementary way to proof this.

Comment: Related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845239/all-the-binomial-coefficients-binomn-i-are-divisible-by-a-prime-p-only?rq=1) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51469/prime-dividing-the-binomial-coefficients?rq=1) for a nice generalization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Otherwise write $n=2^rm$ with $m\ge3$ odd, and consider
$$\binom{n}{2^r}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots (n-2^r+1)}{2^r(2^r-1)(2^r-2)\cdots(2^r-2^r+1)}.$$
Shot that for $0\le t<2^r$, the same power of two divides $n-t$ and $2^r-t$,